# One class of nest classes can't be used as template function typename

Tags: c++

For nest classes, I'd like to use one class of nested classes as template type name, Please see the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct H264 {
    struct NAL_UNIT {
        uint8_t nal_ref_idc;
        uint8_t nal_unit_type;
    };
};

struct H265 {
    struct NAL_UNIT {
        uint8_t nal_unit_type;
        uint8_t nuh_layer_id;
        uint8_t nuh_temporal_id_plus1;
    };
};

template <class T> void PrintNALUnitType(T::NAL_UNIT& nal_unit) {
    printf("nal_unit_type: %d.\n", nal_unit.nal_unit_type);
}

int main() {
    H264::NAL_UNIT h264_nu;
    h264_nu.nal_ref_idc = 2;
    h264_nu.nal_unit_type = 5;

    H265::NAL_UNIT h265_nu;
    h265_nu.nal_unit_type = 35;
    h265_nu.nuh_layer_id = 0;
    h265_nu.nuh_temporal_id_plus1 = 1;

    PrintNALUnitType(h264_nu);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it failed to compile in gcc,

```
namespace.cpp:22:26: error: variable or field ‘PrintNALUnitType’ declared void
 void PrintNALUnitType(T::NAL_UNIT& nal_unit)
                          ^~~~~~~~
namespace.cpp:22:36: error: ‘nal_unit’ was not declared in this scope
 void PrintNALUnitType(T::NAL_UNIT& nal_unit)
                                    ^~~~~~~~
namespace.cpp:22:36: note: suggested alternative: ‘__unix’
 void PrintNALUnitType(T::NAL_UNIT& nal_unit)
                                    ^~~~~~~~
                                    __unix
namespace.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
namespace.cpp:38:5: error: ‘PrintNALUnitType’ was not declared in this scope
     PrintNALUnitType(h264_nu);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know it can be fixed by changing from

```
template <class T>
void PrintNALUnitType(T::NAL_UNIT& nal_unit)
```

to

```
template <class T>
void PrintNALUnitType(T& nal_unit)
```

But I just wonder why it breaks the c++ spec, can somebody give some hints?

Comment: _"it failed to compile in gcc"_ So why didn't you post the compiler error? Your answer may be heavily hinted within that.

Comment: @underscore_d posted the compile error messages

Comment: change `T::NAL_UNIT` to `T`, or `typename T::NAL_UNIT`(which need explicit type parameter)

Comment: what does c++ specify about this? did it say that you can do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
template <class X>
void PrintNALUnitType(typename X::NAL_UNIT& nal_unit) {
    printf("nal_unit_type: %d.\n", nal_unit.nal_unit_type);
}

int main() {  
.
.
    PrintNALUnitType<H265>(h265_nu);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, for template argument deduction from a function call, enclosing class name can not be deduced from nested class name. In your template function:

```
template <class T>
void PrintNALUnitType(typename T::NAL_UNIT& nal_unit) {
   printf("nal_unit_type: %d.\n", nal_unit.nal_unit_type);
}
```

the template parameter T can not be deduced from the type of an argument when the function is called as in `PrintNALUnitType(h264_nu);`.

[[temp.deduct.type]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.type#8) list the possible forms that a template function argument type must have to be deductible:

> A template type argument T, a template template argument TT or a template non-type argument i can be deduced if P and A have one of the following forms:
>
> T
>
> cv-list T
>
> T*
>
> T&
>
> T&&
>
> T[integer-constant]
>
> template-name  (where template-name refers to a class template)
>
> type(T)
>
> T()
>
> T(T)
>
> T type::*
>
> type T::*
>
> T T::*
>
> T (type::*)()
>
> type (T::*)()
>
> type (type::*)(T)
>
> type (T::*)(T)
>
> T (type::*)(T)
>
> T (T::*)()
>
> T (T::*)(T)
>
> type[i]
>
> template-name  (where template-name refers to a class template)
>
> TT
>
> TT
>
> TT<>
>
> where (T) represents a parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]) where at least one parameter type contains a T, and () represents a parameter-type-list where no parameter type contains a T. Similarly,  represents template argument lists where at least one argument contains a T,  represents template argument lists where at least one argument contains an i and <> represents template argument lists where no argument contains a T or an i.

Comment: Thanks, it is too complex for me, I check your link, there is one statement in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.type#5.1, I think it may be the answer. On the other hand, @exs solved this problem.